# How to setup WebClient configuration to use OAuth2 password grant type without client-id?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-webclient

I'm trying to login to an API using a bearer token. The steps are as follows:

1. Send url-encoded username and password to endpoint, and cache token. The request body is:

   ```
    {
     grant_type:password,
     username:username,
     password:password
    }
   ```
2. Use token to call API.

So far, I have been manually doing these steps. However, I have read that Spring Boot already supports this through OAuth2. How can I configure Spring Boot to use this authentication process? There is no client-id or client secret.

Thanks for your help!